# Convert filetime to GMT in Perl

Tags: perl, http-headers, timezone

I am working on some training material for new programmers where I am talking about the HTTP Header, so I am trying to set the Last-Modified manually.  I have everything worked out except for getting the file time to GMT.  Below is what I have so far:

The question is: giving `stat($fh)->mtime` which could be running in any timezone, what code needs to be added to convert to `GMT`?

```
my $scriptFilename = $ENV{'SCRIPT_FILENAME'};
my $timestamp;

my $fh = FileHandle->new;
if ($fh->open("< ${scriptFilename}")) {
    $timestamp = time2str("%a, %e %b %Y %X %Z", stat($fh)->mtime);
    $fh->close;
}

#Last-Modified: Tue, 15 Oct 2019 12:45:26 GMT

print <<"END";
Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Last-Modified: $timestamp

<html>
...
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`time2str`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Date::Format#time2str(TEMPLATE,-TIME-[,-ZONE])) from the `Date::Format` package (I assume that's where `time2str` comes from) takes an optional 3rd argument to specify the timezone.

```
$timestamp = time2str("%a, %e %b %Y %X %Z", stat($fh)->mtime, 'UTC');
```

Comment: Nice. Good catch @mob!

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be some confusion here: the result of mtime is not in any time zone, it is in seconds since the epoch which is a fixed point in time (barring leap seconds which are ignored). Thus all you need to do is represent it in the time zone you want, which is UTC. Another answer mentioned how to do this with the function you had been using, but the usual function to format a time into a string is strftime, which is provided by a couple core modules.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use POSIX 'strftime';
# gmtime interprets the mtime seconds in UTC
my $timestamp = strftime "%a, %e %b %Y %X %Z", gmtime $mtime;

use Time::Piece 'gmtime';
my $timestamp = gmtime($mtime)->strftime("%a, %e %b %Y %X %Z");
```

But your use case is actually a specific date format, the one the HTTP protocol uses, and which will always be in GMT/UTC. There is a module for that: [HTTP::Date](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Date)

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use HTTP::Date 'time2str';
my $timestamp = time2str $mtime;
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically

```
  my $dt = DateTime->new(
      year      => 2000,
      month     => 5,
      day       => 10,
      hour      => 15,
      minute    => 15,
      time_zone => 'America/Los_Angeles',
  );

  print $dt->hour; # prints 15

  $dt->set_time_zone( 'America/Chicago' );

  print $dt->hour; # prints 17
```

See [here](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime#Formatters-And-Stringification) for how to format the output.

Comment: I am sure your code works, but if I am understanding my code correctly, I don't have a DateTime object yet, I have something else.  The question is, without knowing the timezone ahead of time, given *stat($fh)->mtime*, how do I get it to GMT?

Comment: You are givin a training/course as you say. Shouldn't you be able too look into the documentation I linked to and figure out how to create a date time object from a timestamp?